# my array "is not a function" error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store some DOM information into an Array so I can use it elsewhere.

This works if I use a Variable, but if I try to use an Array I get "Arrayname is not a function" error message?  I'm not sure why this would work in a Variable and not an array.

This is the code I'm running:

```
function testmove(total) {
    for (var x=1; x<=total; x++) {
        allstore(x) = jQuery('#block-views-items-block .views-row-1').children('div');
        x++;
    }
}
```

This works:

```
function testmove(total) {
    store1 = jQuery('#block-views-items-block .views-row-1').children('div');       
}
```

Am I missing something/doing something wrong here?

Comment: the thing is that iexplore still supports this syntaxis (up to v11). why? which ecmascript version it was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `allStore` is an array, you should be using it like this:

`allStore[x]`

Comment: ha! oh my god what a complete moron. WEll thats a reason to go and get drunk instead of doing a 'quick' fix to my code on a friday night. thanks all!

Answer (score 5):

You have to use **square brackets** if you want to refer to an array:

```
allstore[x] = ...
```

For further documentation on JavaScript arrays, see [MDN: Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use **square brackets** to reference an array index like this:

```
allstore[x] = jQuery('#block-views-items-block .views-row-1').children('div');
```

Or if you're not looking for a specific index you can use the JavaScript [Push Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) like this:

```
allstore.push(jQuery('#block-views-items-block .views-row-1').children('div'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong kinds of braces; you should use square brackets instead of parentheses when accessing elements of an array by index or key:

```
allstore[x]
```